# Assembly Name and Default Namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, localization

I have an application that uses `localization` . It is ok until a new requirement raised.

Currently my App name is "MyAppName" and Default assembly is "MyAppName".

Now I need to change the exe name to "My Application Name" and default namespace is "MyAppName". I done it throught project->properties->Assembly Name.

Now I am getting exception like :

`'WpfLocalization.LocExtension' value cannot be assigned to property 'MinHeight' of object 'MyAPPName.MainWindow'.
 Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.

 Make sure "My Application Name.Properties.Resources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly 
 "My Application Name" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed. 
 Error at object 'WpfLocalization.LocExtension' in markup file 'My Application Name;component/mainwindow.xaml'.`

I tried :

1. rebuild the localization DLL
2. Change Assembly Name and Default name to another name (which is similar) : **It works**

Please suggest what to do
Thanks,

Comment: you need to replace every place in your application MyAppName with My Application Name

Comment: That will affect namespaces too, Since both are same strings.

Comment: Then you'll have an horrendous manual process to complete, but the answer is still the same. Replace every instance of the namespace `MyAppName` with `My Application Name`. You should also check the project files in a text editor to ensure that you capture *all* of the entries.

Comment: @Sheridan as you can see I am using localization. so if both names are not similar, then localization not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue solved :

The things I done are :

```
1. Change the assembly name and/or namespace name in project -> properties
2. Localization DLL uses(assumes) assembly name as the default namespace. 
   Here we need to provide the namespace name.
3. Rebuild DLL and add reference to project.
```